# Como unir vários updates em tabelas diferentes?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho 3 updates, e as tabelas as quais tenho que dar os updates tem mais 2 milhões de registros, então seria inviável fazer um a um, visto que cada um demora mais de meia hora pra rodar, e ficar esperando um terminar para rodar o outro não é produtivo.

Como fazer para uni-los em um único update, ou até num while/for (tentei fazer isso, mas meu conhecimento em SQL é limitado).

Segue os updates:

```
update reference_bankaccount set internalid = v.internal_id 
from  contract_reference v 
where v.external_id = externalid
and internalid = ''

update reference_vendor set internalid = v.internal_id 
from  contract_reference v 
where v.external_id = externalid
and internalid = ''

update reference_customer set internalid = v.internal_id 
from  contract_reference v 
where v.external_id = externalid
and internalid = ''
```

Procurei aqui no SOpt, mas a galera só tem perguntado em relação a alteração de várias colunas na mesma tabela, não em tabelas diferentes.

Comment: Poderia montar um script, ou montar uma planilha e realizar a atualização com um `COPY`. Se aceitar, elaboro a resposta

Comment: Não pode dar atualizar mais de uma tabela na mesma instrução porque a sintaxe não permite. Não é pela Atomicidade, já que se vários updates estiverem dentro da mesma trasação, a atomicidade é garantida. Como foi comentado, basta executar as 3 instruções de uma vez.

Comment: A resposta do Reginaldo tinha resolvido meu problema, mas ele removeu a mensagem. Mesmo assim, obrigada pelas respostas pessoal. Não sabia que colocando ; no final da transação ele já pulava pra próxima. Vivendo e aprendendo!

Comment: Desculpe-me, rsrs, retirei porque ao mesmo tempo verifiquei que tinha feito uma pergunta boba. De qualquer forma, legal que tenha resolvido assim facilmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver com a ajuda do Reginaldo Rigo da seguinte forma:

```
update reference_bankaccount set internalid = v.internal_id 
from  contract_reference v 
where v.external_id = externalid
and internalid = '';

update reference_vendor set internalid = v.internal_id 
from  contract_reference v 
where v.external_id = externalid
and internalid = '';

update reference_customer set internalid = v.internal_id 
from  contract_reference v 
where v.external_id = externalid
and internalid = '';
```

Acrescentando o ; no final dos updates, eles são executados em sequencia, sem que eu espere acabar um para por para rodar o outro. :)